# Is it better to use bootstrap with the node module or with the downloadable files?

Tags: angular-cli

My question is quite simple but I want to be sure about this,
I am creating a web app using angular-cli,  I want to have the most "updated" (closer to the last features given by bootstrap) and efficient approach, so I was wondering what would be the best for me:

- using the file given by the official bootstrap website
- using the `npm i bootstrap` command

Answer (score 0):

This is not a question with a single universally applicable answer.

NPM offers many benifets like being able to distribute the project amongst developers without worrying about shipping binaries, or people upgrading it one place but not another, allowing remote CI/CD, etc.

That said, some companies may be worried about supply chain attacks, and software repos are a tempting target. when selecting a package from a repo, you have to trust not only the package, and the set of authors (past, present, and future), but also the repo itself.  My CIO just asked me the other day if NuGet or NPM are a vulnerability. I said yes, it could be, but it could also be our salvation, if we have a critical bug in a package and need to upgrade it swiftly.

so there are benefits and tradeoffs between both approaches. Consider your shops requirements and policies.

My personal advise is don't fight your ecosystem. you will be wasting your time, and energy, and sanity tilting at windmills. Development is always moving forward, and if you don't move with it, your career as a dev won't last nearly so long as if you had kept with the community. Repos just aren't somthing you can easily avoid these days, so unless you have a good reason not to, just go with the program as it were.

Comment: thanks for that quick answer full of wisdom